# How to use Firebase Realtime DB Rules in React Native JS

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase for Realtime Chats, I have implemented the whole chat and it is working fine. But I do have a problem with Setuping Rules and Using them in my app.

Here are the rules I am using.

```js
{
   "rules": {
     "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Now How do I use them in my app get to data and write data ?

Here I am getting my DB

```js
  const db = getDatabase();
```

And this is the function to get Chats

```js
      const getChatListing= async() => {
        const reference = ref(db,'chats/');
        onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
            // some operational code
        });
```

Where do I put the auth Uid to validate it on Firebase

I tried to put firebase configs and intialized app in getDatabase function as a param, but it didnt worked.

Comment: Do you want to read read/write from/to all the nodes under the `chats` node (cf. your JS code) or all the nodes under the `chats/uid` node (cf. your Security rules code)?

Comment: Read write for Every thing under chats